# TableView with submenu in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create a menu with submenus for an iOS app.

I dont know what the best approach would be, and am looking for some advice.

I want to move things from one place to another.

> To:
>
> From:

I have country, state, city.

When you click on the tableview that has to and from in it, i want a submenu that shows the list of countries, then when a country is click, a list of states, etc.

Should i have a tableview for each menu type?

countryView
stateView
cityView

Then inside the cityView, when one is selected, i pass that selection back to the main table, with to and from, and display it as the detail for that cell.

Is this the best approach?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Use a `UIPickerView` for this.

Comment: Okay.  So say i have the menuTable, which has to and from.  When you click on the to cell, a new view is pushed that has country, state, city in 3 cells.  Each cell is a pickerView with the content?

Comment: there isnt a single best approach, if you have a lot of data to display tableView are great for that

Comment: Can you populate a pickerView from the selection of another pickerView?  Say cell 1 has a pickerView of countries, can i populate cell 2 pickerView of states based off cell 1s selection?

Comment: @user2891803 you better off using multiple tableView unless the data you want to show is really small

Comment: Dear god do not make cells themselves pickerViews. You'll confuse the gestures within the cell not to mention make a horrible user experience. Quite honestly `UIPickerView` is a bad implementation for this. Imagine putting in `California` as a state. How many cities are there that you have to annoyingly scroll through? Too many for the user. Have each cell push to a VC that has a SearchViewController - You present all the available options but also give them the chance to search for their state/city/country.

Comment: Not all countries have states. You are better off using a picker view for the country (to save on search time) and a search controller for the city/state.

Comment: You should delete this question, is too broad

Comment: @duci9y Search time is actually negligible for list of countries. If your searching of 196 countries takes longer than a user to scroll past 10 countries in a UIPickerView, somethings wrong with the code. Point is that with 196 countries, if you live in Madagascar, you have to scroll through way too many countries in a UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most HIG-compliant would be like so:

[image: Storyboard]

The 'From' and 'To' cells trigger a modal segue to the 'Choose a City' table view controller.

The choose a city controller declares a delegate property and a protocol with a suitable method. The 'Moving' view controller can set itself as the delegate in the `prepareForSegue:` method.

The Choose a City controller can use a suitable string-based search approach to filter through the list of cities. When the user taps a city, the controller dismisses itself and sends a message to the delegate telling it about the location selected. The delegate (here, the 'Moving' view controller) accordingly updates the location shown by the 'From' or 'To' fields.

Put a 'Done' button wherever the controller needs to be explicitly dismissed to continue with the workflow, and a 'Cancel' button wherever it is dismissed implicitly.